# Using Row_Number in Linq where clause

Tags: linq

how can I simulate the following sql query using linq. I just want to have a Row_Number column and use it's values in linq where clause.

```
With t As (
    Select Row_Number() over ( Order by Id ) as 'RowId', * From Orders
) 
Select * From t Where RowId between 1 and 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is just Skip/Take, for paging.

So basically:

```
var result = dataContext.Products.Skip(0).Take(10).ToList();
```

*(Code is untested, written off the top of my head)*